# Configure remark-lint-no-undefined-references plugin/rule 'Allow' option for remark-cli?

Tags: node.js, json, remarkjs, azure-devops-wiki

## Original Question

How do I correctly "*[configure](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-lint#configure)*" the ([unified](https://github.com/unifiedjs/unified#readme), [remark](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark#readme), [remark-lint](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-lint#readme)) [remark-lint-no-undefined-references](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-lint/tree/main/packages/remark-lint-no-undefined-references#readme) plugin/rule ["allow" option](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-lint/tree/main/packages/remark-lint-no-undefined-references#api) for use with the [remark-cli](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark/tree/main/packages/remark-cli#readme)?

My goal is to [configure the rule](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-lint/tree/main/packages/remark-lint-no-undefined-references#api) to ignore the [Azure DevOps Wiki's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-devops-wiki) non-standard table of contents tag, `[[_TOC_]]`. My simplified setup entails:

1. All packages [globally installed](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install#global). Probably not relevant.
2. A parent folder in which I have:

   - A `package.json` file.
   - A `Test` folder containing just the one `Test.md` file whose only content is this one line `[[_TOC_]]`.
3. From a command prompt whose working folder is the aforementioned parent folder, I execute:

   - `remark Test`

### Default Operation

The default operation, i.e. just the plugin/rule specified in the `package.json` file, returns the expected warning. This is, ***presumably***, due to the non-standard tag, `[[_TOC_]]`. This is the warning I wish to turn off.

#### package.json (default)

```json
{
    "remarkConfig": {
        "plugins": [
            "remark-lint-no-undefined-references"
    ]
    }
}
```

#### Execution and Expected Warning (default)

```
C:\..>remark Test
test\Test.md
  1:1-1:10  warning  Found reference to undefined definition  no-undefined-references  remark-lint
   1:2-1:9  warning  Found reference to undefined definition  no-undefined-references  remark-lint

‼ 2 warnings
```

### What I've tried

I've tried to adapt [remark-lint-no-undefined-references API example](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-lint/tree/main/packages/remark-lint-no-undefined-references#api) and [Configuration, 'rules can be configured in one standard way'](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-lint#configure) to my `package.json` file. After much trial and error, I've ended up with this seemingly valid json:

#### package.json

```json
{
    "remarkConfig": {
        "plugins": [
            "remark-lint-no-undefined-references", [1, {
                "allow": ["[[_TOC_]]"]
            }]
        ]
    }
}
```

The [Online JSON Viewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) and [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) indicate it's valid JSON. However, [remark-cli](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark/tree/main/packages/remark-cli#readme) yields this error. Other variations yielded different errors. I am stumped.

```
C:\..>
Test\Test.md
  1:1  error  Error: Cannot parse file `package.json`
Expected preset, not `1`
    at Error (file:///C:/Users/scott.welker/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/remark-cli/node_modules/fault/index.js:39:12)
    at file:///C:/Users/scott.welker/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/remark-cli/node_modules/unified-engine/lib/find-up.js:190:15
    at done (file:///C:/Users/scott.welker/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/remark-cli/node_modules/trough/index.js:145:7)

× 1 error
```

---

## Update 03/14/2022

I've made some progress thanks to [a bit of help on GitHub Issue (#210)](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-lint/pull/210). However, that was not the right avenue and it is closed. My issue remains.

### A Few Things are Apparent

1. My initially inferred JSON, `package.json`, is incorrect. See **Hacked my JSON** below.
2. I failed to appreciate how the non-standard Azure DevOps Wiki table of contents tag, `[[_TOC_]]`, is interpreted. See **Tag Interpretation (console-log)** following.
3. My inferred `package.json` seemingly remains incorrect. See **My JSON Must Still be Wrong** below.

### Hacked my JSON

To overcome `...Error: Cannot parse file 'package.json', Expected preset, not '1'` I hacked my file so that I now have the following. This change overcomes the error and enables me to continue but it is still seemingly incorrect. See **My JSON Must Still be Wrong**.

#### package.json file

```json
{
    "remarkConfig": {
        "plugins": [
            "remark-lint-no-undefined-references", {
                "allow": ["_TOC_", "[_TOC_]"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

### Tag Interpretation (console.log)

After hacking my JSON, I added a [recommended console.log (`..\npm\node_modules\remark-lint-no-undefined-references\index.js`)](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-lint/blob/8e2a554c381f05e0469b493501700bd8e8d19251/packages/remark-lint-no-undefined-references/index.js#L310) of `id`. This reveals that the linting interprets the table of contents tag as two separate bits of concerning markdown, `_TOC_` and `[_TOC_]`. I did not appreciate this. However, the findings below suggest this may not be a problem. See **My JSON Must Still be Wrong**.

#### remark-cli

```
C:\..>remark Test
Id:  _TOC_
Id:  [_TOC_]
Test\Test.md
  1:1-1:10  warning  Found reference to undefined definition  no-undefined-references  remark-lint
   1:2-1:9  warning  Found reference to undefined definition  no-undefined-references  remark-lint

‼ 2 warnings
```

### My JSON Must Still be Wrong

Referring to another location in the source [here (line 126)](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-lint/blob/8e2a554c381f05e0469b493501700bd8e8d19251/packages/remark-lint-no-undefined-references/index.js#L126), when I replace that `const allow` definition with this hard-coded declaration, `const allow = new Set(["_TOC_", "[_TOC_]"])`, I get the desired behavior. E.g.:

#### remark-cli

```
C:\...>remark Test
Test\Test.md: no issues found
```

### Next Steps:

1. See whether I can forgo the `package.json` and instead use pure [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript). Either my JSON is incorrect or it isn't being interpreted correctly.
2. Continue to futz with the JSON. What I've inferred may well be wrong.

   - The following guess also fails to suppress the unwanted warnings:

#### package.json

```json
{
    "remarkConfig": {
        "plugins": [
            "remark-lint-no-undefined-references", [{
                "allow": ["_TOC_", "[_TOC_]"]
            }]
        ]
    }
}
```

---

## Update 03/28/2022

| CAUTION! |
| --- |
| While the setup in this update is valid, the `Test.js` example code is flawed. See **03/30/2022 Update** below. |

Following up on "*Next Step, see whether I can forgo the `package.json` and instead use pure [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript).*"

I seem to have made it work except it suppresses all warnings, not just the few (two) that I am targeting. More development and testing is needed.

### New Setup

1. A new parent Node.js application folder in which I have:

   - Opted to re-install all packages, and some new ones, but not globally (this time):

     - `npm install to-vfile`
     - `npm install vfile-reporter`
     - `npm install remark`
     - `npm install remark-lint`
     - `npm install remark-lint-no-undefined-references`
   - The `node_modules` folder. Created and populated by npm installs (dependencies).
   - A `package.json` file. Created and populated by npm installs.
   - A `package-lock.json` file. Created and populated by npm installs.
   - A copy of the same `Test` folder containing just the one `Test.md` file whose only content is this one line `[[_TOC_]]`.
2. From a command prompt whose working folder is the aforementioned parent folder, I execute my new node/[javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) code:

   - `node Test.js` See following. Code comments illustrate the unexpected suppression of all warnings, even those not targeted.

#### Test.js

**WARNING!** This code is incorrect. See the **03/30/2022 Update** below.

```js
import {reporter} from 'vfile-reporter'
import {remark} from 'remark'
import remarkLint from 'remark-lint'
import remarkLintNoUndefinedReferences from 'remark-lint-no-undefined-references'
import {read} from 'to-vfile'

main()

async function main() {
  const file = await remark()
    .use(remarkLint)
    // This useage results in the expected warnings, '...Found reference to undefined definition...'
    .use(remarkLintNoUndefinedReferences)
    
    // This usage suppresses the warnings, as desired. However, note the next usage.
    //.use(remarkLintNoUndefinedReferences[ { allow: [ '_TOC_', '[_TOC_]' ] }])

    // This usage also suppresses the warning but it shoud not have done so.
    //.use(remarkLintNoUndefinedReferences[ { allow: [ '...', '…' ] }])

    // This usage (and related tests) seem to illustrate that anything in the allowed array suppresses all warnings. 
    //.use(remarkLintNoUndefinedReferences[ { allow: [ '' ] }])
    .process(await read('.\\Test\\Test.md'))

  console.error(reporter(file))
}
```

---

## Update 03/30/2022

Here is a corrected `Test.js` file where my invalid usages are commented out, marked `WRONG`, and the two correct usages are marked `GOOD`. The final usage corrects mistakes made in my 03/28/2022 update. I now have a working [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) version. I just need to adapt this known working version to the [remark-cli's](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark/tree/main/packages/remark-cli#readme) `package.json` file. Getting very close.

I arrived at this `CORRECT`, working usage through trial and error. My trial and error was aided by adding `console.log()` statements to the `..\remark-lint-no-undefined-references\index.js` source and tweaking my javascript code as guided by repeated re-reading of the [remark-lint Configure](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-lint#configure) section.

#### Test.js

```js
import {reporter} from 'vfile-reporter'
import {remark} from 'remark'
import remarkLint from 'remark-lint'
import remarkLintNoUndefinedReferences from 'remark-lint-no-undefined-references'
import {read} from 'to-vfile'

main()

async function main() {
  const file = await remark()
    .use(remarkLint)
  
    // WRONG: This usage seems to suppress the warnings, as desired. However, note the next usage.
    //.use(remarkLintNoUndefinedReferences[ { allow: [ '_TOC_', '[_TOC_]' ] }])

    // WRONG: This usage also seems to supresses the warnings but, it shoud not have done so.
    //.use(remarkLintNoUndefinedReferences[ { allow: [ '...', '…' ] }])

    // WRONG: This usage (and related tests) seem to illustrate that anything in the allowed array suppresses all warnings. 
    //.use(remarkLintNoUndefinedReferences[ { allow: [ '' ] }])

    // GOOD: This usage results in the expected warnings, '...Found reference to undefined definition...'
    //.use(remarkLintNoUndefinedReferences)

    // GOOD: This usage seems to be correct!!
    .use(remarkLintNoUndefinedReferences, [1, { allow: [ '_TOC_', '[_TOC_]' ] }])
    .process(await read('.\\Test\\Test.md'))

  console.error(reporter(file))
}
```

#### Execution and Output

```
C:\..>node Test.js
DEBUG remarkTest: allow contains 2 items.

DEBUG remarkTest Id: '_TOC_'
DEBUG remarkTest Id: '[_TOC_]'
.\Test\Test.md: no issues found
```

Comment: I seem to have identified the [GitHub Issue (#210)](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-lint/pull/210) in which this `allow` feature was added. There is some dialog there. If, or when, it is fruitful, I'll update this question or provide an answer.

Comment: This is a "back burner" task that I won't forget. However, I must neglect it for awhile. If anyone can share an example that successfully configures a rule's "options" via the `package.json' file, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `package.json` below correctly "*[configures](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-lint#configure)*" the  [remark-lint-no-undefined-references](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-lint/tree/main/packages/remark-lint-no-undefined-references#readme) plugin/rule ["allow" option](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-lint/tree/main/packages/remark-lint-no-undefined-references#api) for use with [remark-cli](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark/tree/main/packages/remark-cli#readme).

- **Note:** I also transitioned away from globally installed packages out of an unsubstantiated concern that they might have contributed to my problem. See [Multiple globally installed presets and plugins don’t work #165](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-lint/issues/165). This transition accounts for the added `package.json` "***dependencies***". See following.

#### package.json

I arrived at this by working from my 03/30/2022 update and futzing with varying syntax illustrated in the [Unified Engine, Configuration, Schema](https://github.com/unifiedjs/unified-engine/blob/main/doc/configure.md#schema) section.

Again, my goal is to [configure the rule](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-lint/tree/main/packages/remark-lint-no-undefined-references#api) to ignore the [Azure DevOps Wiki's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-devops-wiki) non-standard table of contents tag, `[[_TOC_]]`.

```json
{
    "remarkConfig": {
        "plugins": {
            "remark-lint-no-undefined-references": { "allow":[ "_TOC_", "[_TOC_]" ] }
        }
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "remark": "^14.0.2",
        "remark-lint": "^9.1.1",
        "remark-lint-no-undefined-references": "^4.1.1"
    }
}
```

#### Execution and Output

Note: my debug `console.log(...)` remains in place.

```
C:\..>remark Test
DEBUG remarkCLITest: allow contains 2 items.

Test\Test.md: no issues found
```

Comment: With this sorted out, I was able to find and fix a number of bad links. Additionally, I discovered two more bits of [Azure DevOps Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-devops-wiki) syntax that can get flagged for "undefined references"; [image attachments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops#images) and [Mermaid diagrams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops#add-mermaid-diagrams-to-a-wiki-page). More work to do but, I love these tools!

Comment: For the [image attachments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops#images) I found that most of mine conformed to `[image.png](...)`. A few did not conform so I edited them to be conformant. Then I modified my config: `"remark-lint-no-undefined-references": { "allow":[ "_TOC_", "[_TOC_]", "image.png" ] }`